# получение коннектов в Netty

Tags: java, netty

Перед тем как написать сюда были предприняты попытки узнать все это у googla, но нечего путного он не выдает, на сайте библиотеки с инфой скудно.

Как на сервере можно получить коннект клиента, чтобы потом с ним работать в отдельных потоках? В old I/O это можно было сделать при помощи `serverSocket.accept()`

Comment: На сколько помню, когда поднимаешь сервер, указываешь хендлер для сервера, и в нем помимо channelRead0 есть методы channelActive, channelInactive, handlerAdded и т.д. Там везде передаётся ChannelHandlerContext из которого лёгко получаешь Channel

Comment: Попробую, отпишусь что получилось))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коннект клиента можно получить следующим образом:
на сервере создается `handler` и переопределяются нужные методы например `channelActive` в этот `handler` можно передать то куда будут складываться коннекты и при удачном подключении вызовется `channelActive` и в нем можно будет вытащить из `ChannelHandlerContext` коннект(`Channel`).

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    server.channel = ctx.channel();
}
```

Дальше  `channel` предоставляет возможность отправки и получения сообщений, но просто так отправить строку или набор байтов не выйдет(у меня не получилось), для этого нужно использовать `ByteBuf`.

```
ByteBuf buf = channel.alloc().buffer();
buf.writeBytes("message".getBytes());
chanel.pipeline().writeAndFlush(buf);
```

P.S надеюсь кому нибудь это пригодится.